# NodeJS application cannot find modules after being bundled by Webpack

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm creating a node/express server that I'm trying to bundle so that I can deploy it onto an IIS server. I should note that this is a backend server only. Once I try to run the code after it has been bundled, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_dotenv__ is not defined
    at eval (webpack:///external_%22dotenv%22?:1:18)
    at Object.dotenv (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:271:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/server/server.js?:4:1)
    at Object../src/server/server.js (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:169:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/server/server.js?:1:18)
    at Object.0 (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:216:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:20:30)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-deployments\server\bundle.js:84:18
```

I understand that there seems to be an error with the dotenv module, however I tried with a basic app that only had express installed, and I got the same error but with express instead of dotenv. I figure this is an issue with my webpack.config.js but I can't seem to figure out what would be causing this problem.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        bundle: ["./src/server/server.js"]
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        importType: 'umd'
    })],
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'server'
        })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `nodeExternals` options. Remove `importType: 'umd'` and re-bundle. I tested this locally with a small `express` app and your exact config and it worked for me.

The issue here is that you're telling webpack that **all** your imports are "external" (not bundled) and that they use `umd` (Universal Module Definition) to expose their contents.

Umd is often used for client side code so it'll run in multiple different environments (`<script>` tags, commonjs, amd, es6 modules and so on). As for server side / Nodejs only modules... not so much. The [default value](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#optionsimporttype-commonjs) of `importType` is `commonjs`, which is Node's native module loading system and what the vast majority of server side packages will be using.

Comment: This absolutely solved the problem! Thank you! It has lead me to another issue that I was wondering if I could ask you. When I move the bundle.js out of the dist folder, the bundle.js no longer has access to what is in the node_modules folder. My understanding is that webpack should be adding functionality from the dependencies into bundle.js. Am I wrong in thinking that? Or is my webpack.config.js simply not properly structured to bundle these dependencies?

Comment: If you want your dependencies to be added to your `bundle.js`, you'll need to remove `nodeExternals` entirely - that is it's entire purpose (keeping the node_modules from being bundled). You'll need to deploy your node_modules folder along with bundle.js if you choose to keep `nodeExternals`.